# SQL Select Multiple Columns based upon Closest TimeStamp

Tags: sql, t-sql

Given query results with the below structure

[image]

I need to write a SQL query to provide me with the DeviceName, Software, CurrentUser, ChangeDate, and LogInTime of the closest LogInTime occurring before the ChangeDate.

So In the image above, I have the three values that would be returned highlighted. The image below is what I would expect from the SQL Query.

[image]

Please note that the query has hundreds of thousands of records. Any 1 server can have multiple different software and multiple different users. The results need to be separated based upon all of these facts.

Below is an edited version of the query that is pulling this information:

```
SELECT DeviceName
    , Software
    , CurrentUser
    , ChangeDate
    , (
        CASE 
            WHEN ActionCode = 39
                THEN actiondate
            ELSE NULL
            END
        ) AS LogInTime
FROM dbo.Info
RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT c.computer_idn
        , c.DeviceName
        , h.ChangeDate
        , h.newstr AS Software
    FROM dbo.history AS H
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Computer AS c
        ON c.computer_idn = h.computer_idn
    WHERE h.tablename LIKE 'AppSoftwareSuites'
        AND ChangeDate > DATEADD(day, - 7, GETDATE())
    ) AS t1
    ON t1.computer_idn = Info.computer_idn
WHERE actioncode = 39
```

I'm stuck as to how to get the results that I want, and I would really rather not create a macro or program with PowerShell/C# so any help is greatly appreciated!

This is what worked!

```
WITH query_cte A
 AS (SELECT devicename, 
            software, 
            currentuser, 
            changedate, 
            logintime, 
            Rank() 
              OVER( 
                partition BY changedate 
                ORDER BY logintime DESC) AS login_rank 
FROM(
SELECT DeviceName
    , Software
    , CurrentUser
    , ChangeDate
    , (
        CASE 
            WHEN ActionCode = 39
                THEN actiondate
            ELSE NULL
            END
        ) AS LogInTime
FROM dbo.Info
RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT c.computer_idn
        , c.DeviceName
        , h.ChangeDate
        , h.newstr AS Software
    FROM dbo.history AS H
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Computer AS c
        ON c.computer_idn = h.computer_idn
    WHERE h.tablename LIKE 'AppSoftwareSuites'
        AND ChangeDate > DATEADD(day, - 7, GETDATE())
    ) AS t1
    ON t1.computer_idn = Info.computer_idn
WHERE actioncode = 39
                )AS t3 
     WHERE  logintime <= changedate) 
SELECT * FROM   query_cte WHERE  login_rank = 1
```

Comment: Left justified SQL... Too hard to read!

Comment: Which table does actioncode belong to?

Comment: ActionCode belongs to dbo.Info

Comment: That means your right join executes as a regular inner join!

Comment: You said: `Any 1 server can have multiple different software and multiple different users. The results need to be separated based upon all of these facts`. If  so, then why in your expected result, there is no user "Bob" at all ?

Comment: Because Bob did not have the most recent login time for any server, software, or software. I apologize if I misspoke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use something like `ROWRANK`, partitioning by your three return fields and ordering by `LoginTime DESC`.

Doing the bulk of your query in a CTE means that you can filter out everything that's not the latest LoginTime.

```
WITH query_cte AS (
    Select DeviceName,  Software, CurrentUser,  ChangeDate,
    (case when ActionCode = 39 then actiondate else  null end) as LogInTime,
    ROWRANK OVER(PARTITION BY ChangeDate ORDER BY LoginTime DESC) as login_rank
    from dbo.Info right outer join 
    (select distinct c.computer_idn, c.DeviceName, h.ChangeDate, h.newstr as Software
    from dbo.history as H
    left outer join dbo.Computer as c on c.computer_idn = h.computer_idn
    where h.tablename like 'AppSoftwareSuites' 
    AND ChangeDate > DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE()) ) as t1
    on t1.computer_idn = Info.computer_idn
    WHERE actioncode =  39
    AND LoginTime < ChangeDate
)
SELECT * from query_cte WHERE login_rank = 1
```

- caveat: code from memory, I'll try and mock it up later to test it out.

Comment: I was able to modify this to work perfectly! I'll post what worked in the initial question.

Comment: Glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 0):

For you to get good help you should show the relationship of tables

SELECT DeviceName, Software, CurrentUser, ChangeDate, LogInTime FROM tableName 
WHERE LogInTime <= ChangeDate

Comment: There can be potentially hundreds of login times that are less than or equal to the change date.